# Call Action in Controller From View and send parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirect, model-view-controller

I am trying to call a method inside a controller in MVC from a javascript action. The javascript action is supposed to invoke this method inside the controller and send some parameters to it.

My Javascript code looks like this:

```
location.href = '@Url.Content("~/Areas/MyArea/MyMethod/"+Model.MyId)';
```

My Method is defined as follows:

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult MyMethod(int? MyId) 
{ 
   doSomething(MyId); 
   return View("MyView"); 
}
```

However, when i debug the application, when the method is called the MyId parameter is passed as null and not as the current value of the MyId parameter in my model. What can I do to correctly send or retrieve this value? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route definition I suppose that the parameter is called `{id}` and not `{MyId}`:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "MyArea_default",
        "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

So try to be more consistent and adapt your controller action parameter name accordingly:

```
[HttpGet] 
public ActionResult MyMethod(int? id) 
{ 
    doSomething(id); 
    return View("MyView");
}
```

Also you probably wanna use url helpers instead of hardcoding some url patterns in your javascript code:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("MyMethod", "SomeControllerName", new { area = "MyArea", id = Model.MyId })';
```

The `Url.Content` helper is used to reference static resources in your site such as javascript, css and image files. For controller actions it's much better to use the `Url.Action` helper method.