# Javascript url content with parameter?

Tags: javascript, url-routing, location-href

I wish to pass 'selectlang' parameter in javascript and redirect to the MVC controller but the var 'selectlang' have error and mention that it does not exist in current content? Please guide me thanks!

My javascript:

```
 $('.filterlang').on("click", function () {
            var selectlang = document.getElementById("Language").value;
            location.href = '@Url.Content("~/SURV_Main/SURV_Main_Details/?key=" + Model.Survey_Key +"&Language=" + selectlang)';

        });
```

filterlang is button class and "Language" is dropdownlist id.

Comment: `"&Language="+selectlang`, there is a `+ `missing between the variable and the string.

Comment: its same after i add the + symbol.

Comment: check in developer tools, are you getting any value for  `document.getElementById("Language").value`

Comment: what is .filterlang and what is id Language ? Can you describe ti better or show more code?

Comment: @IgorIlic question updated. Thanks!

Comment: @rajuGT yes i do get value when alert ( selectlang ).

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744945/call-action-in-controller-from-view-and-send-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
$(document).on(".filterLang", "click", function(){
   var selectedLang = $("#Language").val(); // if it is normal dropdown, this will work for both cases
   var selected2Lang = $("#Language").select2("val"); // if it is select2 dropdown
   window.location = '@Url.Content("~/SURV_Main/SURV_Main_Details/?key=" + Model.Survey_Key +"&Language=' + selectlang + '")';
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have no idea why the var  + selectlang not recognize :( it say it does not exist in current content.

Comment: @Edward.K I have update the code, you see one of the problems was that you were trying to access the value of selectedLang from c# code and it gave you and error because the c# does not have that variable declared.